# Combining xstring with xkeyval

Tags: xstring, markdown, xkeyval

I'm trying to extend the [markdown](https://ctan.org/pkg/markdown) package so that I can pass options to `\includegraphics` and have them override defaults, something like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[hybrid]{markdown}

\renewcommand{\markdownRendererImage}[4]{
  \StrCut{#1}{,}{\sclabel}{\scoptions}
  \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,\scoptions]{#3}
    \caption{#4}
    \label{\sclabel}
  \end{figure}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}
![fig:example,width=10px](example.png "Lorem ipsum...")
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this code results in an error:

```
! Package xkeyval Error: `width=10px' undefined in families `Gin'.
```

I understand that `\StrCut` is somehow bundling up `\sclabel` and `xkeyval` doesn't know how to unpack it into key-value pairs, but I'm at a loss as to how to fix it. I've tried every combination I can think of of `xstring`'s `\detokenize`, `\tokenize`, `\expandafter` etc. macros and I'm just very confused.

Here's a simpler MWE that doesn't depend on `markdown` and that shows some of the weird behavior I've already discovered:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\markdownRendererImage}[2]{
  \StrCut{#1}{,}{\sclabel}{\scoptions}
  \includegraphics[\scoptions]{#2}
}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=10px]{example1.png} % works as expected
\markdownRendererImage{fig:example}{example2.png} % works as expected (\scoptions is empty)
\markdownRendererImage{fig:example,width=10px}{example3.png} % fails with error, uses default settings
\markdownRendererImage{fig:example,{width=10px}}{example4.png} % fails without error, uses default settings

\end{document}
```

I'm sure there's a simple way to do this but I can't crack it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need to expand `\scoptions` before `\includegraphics` sees it. In the second example it would be `\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\scoptions]{#2}`. In the first example it's a bit trickier because the `\scoptions` is further away: `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,\unexpanded\expandafter{\scoptions}]}\x{#3}`.

Comment: Thank you! Your second line of code worked perfectly and there's no way I could've figured it out from the duplicate question.